# Finding rate of return of bond sold before maturity

Tags: finance-mathematics

You purchase a bond today for $980; M=$1000, the coupon rate is 4% paid semi-annually, and there are n=7 years to maturity.  If you sell the bond for $1025 in six months time, what is your rate of return?

Would I be correct in saying that the rate of return is 1,025 of the sale, plus the 20 dollar coupon divided by the initial sale?

Comment: This is correct if you are computing the six-months return. Do you need to translate it into an annual rate of return? Or monthly? or is it OK as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but I would check the size of the coupon if I were you.

Comment: Do you think there is something wrong with the coupon calculation? I see 4% on a face value of 1000, paid semiannually, I get 20 like the OP.

Comment: The question originally had a $200 coupon (it's been edited).